# java.xml XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING cannot resolve or not is a field

Tags: java, xml, spring, eclipse, maven

I work with Eclipse, Spring MVC and Maven.The Java version is 1.6

I have the following method

```
public static DocumentBuilder getBuilder(ServletContext servletContext)
{
 DocumentBuilderFactory factory =DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setValidating(true);            

        DocumentBuilder builder = null;
        try {
            factory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
```

I have an error in the eclipse editor in the line:

```
factory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING,
```

The error is

```
FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING cannot be resolved or not is a field
```

In the editor Eclipse I see:

[image]

Maven dependencies are:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Why don't I have the variable

```
XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING ?
```

Answer (score 20):

I don't know if there is your case, but I solve the problem **configuring the source folders in my Java project Build Path**, following these steps:

1. Right click on the project and select "Properties"
2. Select "Java Build Path" from the left menu
3. Select "Order and Export" tab
4. Move "JRE System Library" on Top and Apply

In this way the Java libraries are used before the others.

Answer (score 4):

One of the libraries in your classpath contains an older version of `javax.xml.XMLConstants`.  You need to find and remove that library.  Try using `Ctrl + Shift + T` or select `Navigate -> Open Type` in Eclipse to find the offending jar file.

Also, you have at least two libraries, Xerces and Xalan, that aren't necessary and can be removed, as they're bundled with the JDK.

Comment: This did not help at all for me

Comment: In my case, it was STAX API bundled with Apache POI libs. Used @Ale's solution. This solution should help for excluding jars in pom.xml. Thanks!